# C++ UML generation/edit tool

Tags: c++, documentation-generator, uml

What I want is a proper UML tool for C++;
I need the following features:

- **generation of class diagram from (complex) c++ source**

  - including class members
  - showing members as relationships where possible
  - showing class hierarchy
- **support for stl shared/unique/weak ptrs (C++ 11)**
- **possibility to rearrange/edit the resulting diagram**

  - drag shapes around
  - filter visibility of individual members
  - hide destructors/operators to get a clear overview (nice if it could be toggled automatically, but doing this manually is also an option)
- support for (multiple) namespaces

And would really like it if it could:

- apply the changes to the existing code
- integrate with visual studio
- support forward declarations
- support Qt, boost & stl
- support multiple code directories
- support preprocessor directives
- export images
- responsive user interface
- usually I'm working under Windows but if a great tool is available for Mac/Linux I would still consider to use it

It's not that there aren't tools but I can't find one that suits the job yet;
I'm at the start of a refactoring cycle where the structure and ownership of the data containers will change, which has a huge impact. I would like to make a design / change design plan to be sure that surprises are prevented as much as possible, in the end 90% of the existing codebase will be reused but the underlying structure with relation to threading would be different.

Kind Regards & thanks in advance